# StandardFilterFactory missing in Hiberntae Search 6.0.0.Beta2

Tags: hibernate-search

I started playing around with Hibernate Search 6.0.0.Beta2 but found that `StandardFilterFactory` is missing in this new version. I could not find any replacement for this in migration docs. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StandardFilterFactory` is a Lucene class, not a Hibernate Search class. Hibernate Search upgraded from Lucene 5.5 to 8, and the class was removed from Lucene 8.

This filter was removed from Lucene because [it was just a no-op](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardFilterFactory.html) and apparently has been a no-op [for a very long time](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/filter-descriptions.html#standard-filter) (Lucene 3.x).

You should be able to just remove it from your analyzer.